# regex : avoid group - url domain name

Tags: regex, python-3.x, conditional-statements

I wrote this regex for the re module which, as far as I know, works as expected :

```
^(https?://)([\w\.-]+)[\./]*(?(1)(domain-name.com))
```

run against a list of urls, it matches only the ones containing **domain-name.com**. But I don't understand why :

```
^(https?://)([\w\.-]+)[\./]*(?(1)(!(domain-name.com)))
```

does not return all the other urls. Actually it never matches anything.

Thank you

on [pythex](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5E(https%3F%3A%2F%2F)(%5B%5Cw%5C.-%5D%2B)%5B%5C.%2F%5D*(%3F(1)(domain-name.com))&test_string=http%3A%2F%2Fsupport.domain-name.com%2Fmember%2Flicense_serial.php&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: `!` matches the `!` character literally, it does not mean "negation".

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, but based on your regex patterns alone, you have two changes to make. The first is in `domain-name.com` you need to escape the `.`. The second change is the if clause. In regex `!` is interpreted literally, so when you put `!(domain-name.com)` it's trying to match `!domain-name.com` where `.` is any character. Change it to `^(https?://)([\w\.-]+)[\./]*(?(1)|(domain-name\.com))`. Notice there's an `|` in there. The if clause syntax is `(?(condition)true|false)`

Comment: @ctwheels I have a bunch of urls and I need to assert which ones are from the domain name I am on, and which ones are externals. Hope it's more clear. Even with the corrected syntax (thanks ;)), it doesn't do what I need.

Comment: @JohnDoe is there a reason you check whether or not the first capture group is set? I mean your regex won't even match if the first capture group isn't set anyway, so there's no point in using an if clause

Comment: I need it to be full url form because there are some local links to eliminate too : ../local.link or local/links.html form.

Comment: @JohnDoe please see my answer below. Based on all the information you've provided, I believe this is what you're seeking.

Comment: Well I must say : yes I believe :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Matching domain-name.com

To match `domain-name.com` domains, use the following.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/eBYpDL/4)

```
^https?://(?:\w+(?:-\w+)*\.)*domain-name\.com(?=$|/)
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `https?` Match `http` or `https` (`s` is optional)
- `://` Match this literally
- `(?:\w+(?:-\w+)*\.)*` Match any number of subdomains. A subdomain cannot begin or end with `-`, so this subpattern does as follows:

  - `\w+` Match one or more word characters
  - `(?:-\w+)*` Match the following any number of times

    - `-` Match this literally
    - `\w+` Match one or more word characters
  - `\.` Match the dot character literally
- `domain-name\.com` Matches `domain-name.com` literally
- `(?=$|[/?#])` Positive lookahead ensuring either the end of the line or a character in the set `/?#` follows

#### Matching non-domain-name.com

To match non-`domain-name.com` domains, use the following.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/eBYpDL/5)

```
^https?://(?:\w+(?:-\w+)*\.)*(?!domain-name\.com)[\w-]+\.[\w-]+(?=$|/)
```

This is the same as the first pattern except it uses `(?!domain-name\.com)[\w-]+\.[\w-]+`. This matches any domain that doesn't match `domain-name.com` literally

Comment: Thanks. ?: is overlapping group, isn't it ? what line of thinking made you come up with this ? if it's not too much asking. :)

Comment: @JohnDoe it's just a lot of practice with regex. `(?:)` is a non-capture group.

Comment: I just mastered regex yesterday night.. the pdf. So.. the basically new born says thanks again. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use negative lookahead with ?! instead of !

```
^(https?://)([\w\.-]+)[\./]*(?(1)(?!(domain-name.com)))
```